# I'm looking for an introduction to mathematical symbols and jargon.

Tags: self-learning, machine-learning, math-history

I want to understand how to read mathematical symbols. At the moment I've not found a great way to translate mathematical symbols into a language I can understand. Rather than taking a course in linear algebra or real analysis and waiting for a teacher to introduce one symbol to me, I'd like it if I could survey everything in the lexicon of mathematics, including some basic examples and how they can relate to more advanced examples.

For context: I'm interest in learning more about entropy, black hole and quantum dynamics and so on. I can gain a 30,000 ft view from paragraphs of text, but the mathematical symbols aren't easy to understand, and because they are often rendered as images you cannot look them up on Google.

Consequently, it's difficult for me to find a way into this world because it's not clear how to begin or where to derive the information I seek.

Comment: The language of math is based on math. logic and set theory.

Comment: Generally symbols/terms are introduced as a way to streamline concepts, and frequently what a symbol/term means is context-dependent.  I'm not sure you're going to be able to "survey everything in the lexicon of mathematics" without starting with a particular subject.

Comment: I don't know if this would work very well unless you are already well-versed in the area.  Learning the language of math is very different from an ordinary language.  The difference is that in math, definitions have a hierarchical order - every definition depends on some other definition, all the way down to axioms. You need to build your way up in the correct order to understand them.  The notation is also going to be different depending on the field.  I'd say your best bet is just to use ordinary physics textbooks and look up the symbols there.

Comment: (also if you want to be able to look up the names of symbols from the shape, you might try [detexifier](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html))

Comment: Can you give examples of the symbols that you want to know about? I think that will help us point you into the correct direction.

Comment: @DMcMor I pray it's not an original idea. To take any given mathematical symbol and "point to" it's various applications. To say, with accuracy, when the symbol was first inscribed and for what purpose, the date of it's inauguration into the lexicon of mathematics. I do not want to start with a particular subject. I want a chronological list of cases and subjects.

Comment: @JairTaylor Thank you for sharing detextifier. On your other comment: Yes, I know definitions have a hierarchical order. However, with today's information tech, what I'd like to see is a "tree" of that order clearly illuminated. This way, I could choose: reaction diffusion systems, on the one hand, and some equations on information theory, on the other hand (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) and understand the tree and nothing but the tree, then compare trees.

Comment: @starcat That sounds very useful. Maybe you're the one to make it.